# How do I add a new keyserver to upload my PGP keys

Tags: gnupg, seahorse, keyserver

I want to add a new destination server to appear as an option to publish my PGP key to in Seahorse. How do I do this in Ubuntu?

View of Seahorse possible keyservers:

[image: View of Seahorse possible keyservers.]

I successfully did so under Arch Linux by adding the keyserver to

```
~/.gnupg/gpg.conf
```

which doesn't exist in Ubuntu. Should I create the file or can I do it directly from Seahorse?

Any help is appreciated as I can't find any solutions for Ubuntu on the Web. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can set up key servers in `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`, but those settings are not considered by Seahorse as it forces GnuPG to use the key server configured in seahorse instead. With other words, if you set up key servers in `gpg.conf`, they will be used when you manually run `gpg` on the command line or within other applications interfacing GnuPG, but not Seahorse.

Instead, press the "Add" button to add a new key server in seahorse (in the configuration panel you posted as screenshot) and afterwards select it in "Publish keys to:".

Most of the OpenPGP key servers are organized in the SKS synchronizing key server network. Uploading to any of those is sufficient, the changes are then propagated to the other servers automatically (which will usually take some minutes).

Comment: I need further explanation. What port do I specify for the server. I put in 80 and the box stays grayed out. Also, can I force Seahorse to read gpg.conf?  I'm trying to set up a specific secure keyserver with special settings.

Comment: No, you cannot configure Seahorse to obey GnuPG's settings -- you will have to configure the server twize. `80` seems like a port, not a hostname. You have to configure the key server's hostname in the server field.